# android : zoom/pan in canvas

Tags: android, opengl-es, zooming

I want to zoom/pan in the canvas . the canvas contains different objects , images ...
I find some example of zooming in map , images and even web but still don't know how can I zoom/pan into a complete canvas that contain several different objects .

please consider that i'm new to android and opengl . I would appreciate if you give me an example that could be run.